# How to add loading screen sign to data table while using ajax OnSubmit event to load data into it

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, datatable, datatables, onsubmit

So I have been using ajax calls for loading data into my data table based on three drop down list for selecting the search parameters. Since the page is not getting refreshed on each search button click, the data for the previous search remains there until the new data is fetched and displayed( approx. 5 to 8 seconds since there are almost 12000 records). I have tried to use processing attribute of data table but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us the relevant code with some sample data, for a [mre]. Also, you can show us what you have researched and what you have already tried. (You may want to consider using [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) instead.)

Comment: More generally, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour] and read [ask] for further guidance on how to write a good site-appropriate question - one that will be more likely to receive good answers.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the datatables js cdn properly?
try table options like this in js

language: {
search: "SEARCH JOBS" ,
"processing": "<span style='color:Teal;background-color:black';> Fetching From Server. Hold on...",
zeroRecords: ", we are unable to match your search"} ,   scrollCollapse: true,
search: {"search": "prefix a search string here" },

** also try adding the latest js and css, they got an inbuilt animation when data is being processed